# Unity: Build completed with a result of 'failed' - Native error= mono-io-layer-error (2)

Tags: unity, android, macos

I am getting the following errors in Unity 2020.3.5f1 on macOS 10.15.6, when trying to build for Android:

[image]

Full errors below. Any help is appreciated.

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.5f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/deploy/netcoreapp3.1/UnityLinker', CommandLine='@"/Users/Chris/source/unity/BallsFX/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed/response.rsp"', CurrentDirectory='/Users/Chris/source/unity/BallsFX/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed', Native error= mono-io-layer-error (2)
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at <aa976c2104104b7ca9e1785715722c9d>:0)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <aa976c2104104b7ca9e1785715722c9d>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:48)
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:32)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:102)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunNetCoreProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:91)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyLinker (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] args, System.String& out, System.String& err, System.String linkerPath, System.String workingDirectory) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:155)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssembliesTo (System.String outputFolder, System.String& output, System.String& error, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] linkXmlFiles, UnityEditorInternal.UnityLinkerRunInformation runInformation) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:146)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyStripper (UnityEditorInternal.UnityLinkerRunInformation runInformation) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:261)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssemblies (System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, UnityEditorInternal.BaseUnityLinkerPlatformProvider unityLinkerPlatformProvider, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider il2cppPlatformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:167)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:577)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:269)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:337)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:123)
```

---

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 146 seconds (146281 ms)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:123)
```

---

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002be] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:123)
```

Comment: Are you using the Process class, Configuration Manager, or System.Reflection.Emit anywhere? [Searching for this specific error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mono-io-layer-error+unity+build) turns up [this thread about IL2CPP builds not supporting these](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-il2cpp-and-process-start.533988/)

Comment: Hi @DMGregory. No, I'm not using any of those anywhere

Comment: @ChrisC Hello, Chris, have you solved this problem? I've been stuck with it for a few days

Comment: @ming, no, unfortunately not yet - have been working on something else lately. Sorry :/